# Setup a connection between my phone and pc

Tags: router, ftp, connection

not sure if this belongs here so pardon me if it doesn't.

I'm trying to test my `ftp client` android app, so in order to do that I want to set up a connection between my phone and PC.

I'm using pythons `pyftpdlib` to create an `ftp server` on my computer. Both my computer and phone are connected to the same d-link router via wifi. I understood that I somehow need configure my router to route my phone to my computer.

If you need more details I'd be happy to add them.

### **UPDATE**

Here are the devices that are connected to my router via wifi: [Connected wifi devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52xzS.png). As you can see my pc has ip: `10.0.0.11` while my phone seems to have: `10.209.12.109`.
However, when checking into my phone, it looks like it has entirely different ip: `10.0.0.4`, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOESc.png).
I've failed to ping from/to my pc to my phone with either addresses: `destination host unreachable`.
I did manage to connect them using hotspot on my phone, but that is kinda obvious...

### **UPDATE 2- SOLVED**

After resetting my router to factory settings, both my phone and computer are now on the same subnet and I'm able to connect them easily.
Thanks a lot for all the help guys!

Comment: If your phone and PC are on the same WiFi network and have the same IP subnet, then you shouldn't need to do anything beyond make sure they can actually ping through to each other, and given that you already have the ftp client/server stuff setup, nothing more should need be done except connect and start the FTP session .. are you not able to have the phone/PC see each other?

Comment: Apparently my phone and PC aren't on the same subnet, any idea on how to change that? Pc- 10.0.0.11, phone-10.0.x.y. x!=0

Comment: Can you not specify an IP address manually for your phone or computer, putting them in the same subnet? What subnet mask are you using, as if it's not 255.255.255.0 you could still be able to communicate between the devices anyway.

Comment: Added more details. Somehow my router sees my phone ip as something different..,